# Java/android: Help understanding this construct, is it a method or anonymous class?

Tags: java, android

I have been working with a library and I notice the following construct.

```
String run(String url) throws IOException {
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

I am having difficulty in identifying if it is an anonymous class as I don't see it using the interface or concrete class.

Or is it a just a normal method that does a throws `IOException`.

I am coming from a different programming background and looks kind of strange for me.

Are you forced to use throws ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about the presence of `throws IOException`, you must declare it using the `throws` keyword, because it is a [*checked exception*](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129).

So basically

```
String       run    (String url) throws IOException { ... }
^            ^       ^           ^ 
method       method  param type  marks checked        ^
return type  name    and name    exceptions the       method body
                                 method may throw
```

Basically, checked exception in Java is any subclass of `Throwable` which does not inherit from `RuntimeException` or `Error`. Whenever your code throws a checked exception, the Java compiler forces you to either catch it or declare it using the `throws` keyword.

Checked exceptions allow you to verify at compile time that you are either handling exceptions or declaring them to be thrown: When you call a method like `run()`, the compiler will warn you that you must do something about it (catch or declare). For some explanation why Java enforces this, see e.g. [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6115896/2032064).

---

The article linked above explains what is the semantical difference between checked (e.g. `NullPointerException`) and unchecked exceptions (e.g. `IOException`)

> Unchecked runtime exceptions represent conditions that, generally speaking, reflect errors in your program's logic and cannot be reasonably recovered from at run time
>
> Checked exceptions represent invalid conditions in areas outside the immediate control of the program (invalid user input, database problems, network outages, absent files)

Comment: ahh so using throws.. passes any error it back up the chain.... until somebody does a try...catchh....

Answer (score 1):

It is a method.

The signature of the method is `String run(String url) throws IOException`. It means that the method name is `run`; that the method take a `String` as argument; return another `String` and may throw an `IOException`.

Comment: Ah Ok, thanks, so I presume if I call this method outside I would have to wrap it in try -- catch otherwise java complains ? right?  It is normal for methods to define that they throw something ?

Comment: If you use this method inside your own method, you will have to use it inside a try catch blocks ... or declare that your method can throw an exception using the keyword `throws`. Exception are used to report an error that need to interrupt the current excecution